# How to pre/populate database records with CodeFirst approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to write application using TDD and CodeFirst in ASP.NET MVC following 20486B training course guide, but I've stumbled upon a technical/methodology issue which I'll try to describe here. When I'll be coding my application I'd like to prepopulate the database which will be rebuilt each time I build/run/publish the app (as I am understanding CodeFirst). First that came to mind was to create a `initial_data.sql` script file with a bunch of inserts/updates on tables which will be fired up every build/run/publish of my app. It may work with small initial data set, but what when I would have to modify the application, which already would have a larger set of data in the database?

How can I "include" my `initial_data.sql` file each time Database is being rebuilt? 
and second question
How I can CodeFirst on an existing database preserving records that are already in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the `Seed()` method in the Configuration class and load any data in there.

The `Seed()` method will be run every time the database is updated / migrations are run so make sure that it handles existing data gracefully without duplicate inserts etc.

In the `Seed()` method you have access to a `DbContext()` instance which you can use to execute SQL, but it also means you can use the ordinary EF API to update date. Specifically the `AddOrUpdate()` extension is great to use for loading initial data.